# Which Master Page Event fired on loading or after loading every content page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

On loading of every content page, I want to get content page name. So I want to know that which Master Page event is fired on every content page load ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a resource that might help, it states the events that ocur for ASP.NET pages:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/03/08/asp-net-page-events-lifecycle.aspx

1. Page.OnPreInit
2. MasterPageControl.OnInit (for each control on the master page)
3. Control.OnInit (for each contol on the page)
4. MasterPage.OnInit
5. Page.OnInit
6. Page.OnInitComplete
7. Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium
8. Page.LoadViewState
9. MasterPage.LoadViewState
10. Page.OnPreLoad
11. Page.OnLoad
12. MasterPage.OnLoad
13. MasterPageControl.OnLoad (for each control on the master page)
14. Control.OnLoad (for each control on the page)
15. OnXXX (control event)
16. MasterPage.OnBubbleEvent
17. Page.OnBubbleEvent
18. Page.OnLoadComplete
19. Page.OnPreRender
20. MasterPage.OnPreRender
21. MasterPageControl.OnPreRender (for each control on the master page)
22. Control.OnPreRender (for each control on the page)
23. Page.OnPreRenderComplete
24. MasterPageControl.SaveControlState (for each control on the master
     page)
25. Control.SaveControlState (for each control on the page)
26. Page.SaveViewState
27. MasterPage.SaveViewState
28. Page.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium
29. Page.OnSaveStateComplete
30. MasterPageControl.OnUnload (for each control on the master page)
31. Control.OnUnload (for each control on the page)
32. MasterPage.OnUnload
33. Page.OnUnload

Also here is [the official documentation about ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which goes into detail about all the events. Hopefully this will help you.

EDIT;

Hmmm, actually the above looks a bit over the top. It looks like all you need to do is - in each content page, make sure you reference the master page in the ASPX file:

`<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Masters/Master1.master" %>`

Then in the master page have a public method such as:

```
public void LogContentPageName(string name)
{
    // Do whatever you want with the passed name.
}
```

Then in the Page_Load event of the content pages you can do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    Master.LogContentPageName("Whatever");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below event

> protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
>          //do your stuff here }